# Is there a free/open-source equivalent of mailing list managers such as MailChimp or ConstantContact, etc..?

Tags: php, mysql, email

MailChimp is a very nicely done service, where they tell you things like %clicked, and Google Analytics of recent email campaigns. They are similar to other sites like ConstantContact and CampaignMonitor, and many many others.

**Is there anything similar to MailChimp which is open-source or free? 
Or is there anything that could be easily modified to resemble mailchimp for use in-house?**

It is simply too expensive once you have a couple thousand email addresses.

Any ideas would be helpful.
I prefer any languages, but ideally HTML/PHP/MySQL...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[phpList](http://www.phplist.com/)

> ```
> * double opt-in subscription mechanism
> * scheduling
> * RSS
> * list segmentation
> * click-tracking
> * attachments
> * bounce management
> ```

Comment: phpList is just what I was looking for. it's very well made. thanks!

Comment: phpList not free anymore

Comment: phpList is now offered as a paid service, but there is still the open source version at: https://www.phplist.org/

Answer (score 4):

At the Free Software Foundation, we use CiviCRM to send emails out to 50k+ mailing list, http://civicrm.org/.

Answer (score 2):

[MailMan](http://www.gnu.org/software/mailman/index.html)

> Mailman is free software for managing
>   electronic mail discussion and
>   e-newsletter lists. Mailman is
>   integrated with the web, making it
>   easy for users to manage their
>   accounts and for list owners to
>   administer their lists. Mailman
>   supports built-in archiving, automatic
>   bounce processing, content filtering,
>   digest delivery, spam filters, and
>   more.

Comment: do you know if it tells me how many people click on my links/ how many people viewed it?

Comment: @chris: phpList does that for you.

Comment: @AlixAxel Do you mean that phplist is better than mailman? As i know mailman is widely used on cpanel and some other. Do you know which of them are better? thx. (check for them here https://www.google.com/search?q=phplist+vs+mailman&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8). I understand that phpList is more a email list than mailman, wich is a discussion mechanism. I choose phpList :)

Comment: You would need to inject your own analytics tracking system on top of it while generating your email campaigns.

Answer (score 2):

[OpenEMM](http://www.openemm.org/)

> OpenEMM is a feature-rich enterprise
>   software for professional e-mail
>   newsletters and e-mail marketing. It
>   offers sophisticated bounce
>   management, link tracking, lots of
>   statistics and a script feature to set
>   up transaction mails (data, event and
>   time triggered).   OpenEMM is the
>   first open source application for
>   e-mail marketing. Its code base has
>   been developed since 1999 and is used
>   (as part of the commercial ASP product
>   E-Marketing Manager) by companies like
>   IBM, Siemens and Deutsche Telekom.
>   OpenEMM offers already more than 95%
>   of the functionality of most
>   commercial products and some features
>   commercial products do not offer right
>   now (i.e. MySQL support).

Comment: Im sure that the 5% of tools that are not shared for free are just the tools that all the people really need. Opensource do not mean free to use.

Comment: @erm3nda Er... what? The question asks for "open-source or free" pretty clearly.

Comment: Sure. I don't say the opossite and I'm not sure about how god is a 95% of the software.